# Equality in EF objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Is it safe to assume that two entity pointers in EF always are [equal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) (assuming they point to the same row and database context)? No matter how I traverse through connection tables etc. to access them.

Or are there any exceptions? As far as I can tell, they will always reference the same object, and thus always be equal.

```
Person p1 = dbcontext.Persons.FirstOrDefault();
Person p2 = dbcontext.Persons.FirstOrdefault();
Debug.Write(p1.Equals(p2)); // true
```

Comment: How do you ensure, that you are the only one accessing the data source in the timespan your code takes to execute?

Comment: If they are from the same `dbcontext` you could be true, but I'm not 100% positive. If they are from different `dbcontext`'s, then absolutely not.

Comment: @Serv Well, based on the assumption that the source isn't modified.

Comment: @Maarten Yes, I updated my question because I'm just talking about the same context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, when an object has been queried, the object change tracking feature (if enabled) will return the same object that was already queried.  By default it's enabled.  If you refresh the object, then that might not be the case (meaning the Refresh method on the context).

I would not guarantee this behavior 100%...

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I will use an extension that compares equality by keys instead just in case

Comment: A good approach; just make sure you're always comparing the same objects in that case :-)